# c++ 継承時の仮想関数の呼び出しについて

Tags: c++, c++11

c++の仮想関数について質問です。
次のように非常に単純なBaseとそれを継承したDerivedを用意します。

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
virtual void f()
{
   std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
}
};

struct Derived : Base {
void f() override
{
    std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
}
};

int main()
{
  {
    Derived d;
    Base b = d;

    b.f();
  }

  {
    Derived d;
    Base& b = d;

    b.f();
  }
}
```

実行結果が、

```
Base
Derived
```

となります。

なぜ前者ではBaseのf()が呼ばれてしまうのでしょうか。

Comment: FYI: この振る舞いはオブジェクトのスライシング(slicing)とも呼ばれます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。スライシングで調べたらいろいろと情報が出てきて、理解に役立ちそうです。

Answer (score 5):

```
Base b = d;
```

の意味は、`Base`型のインスタンス`b`を新たに作成し、初期化の値として`d`を使う、ということです。つまり、`b`は`Base`そのものなので、`Base`の`f()`が呼ばれます。

```
Base& b = d;
```

は、`b`は参照型なので、中身は`d`です。なので`Derived`の`f()`が呼ばれます。

Comment: なんとなくわかりました。ありがとうございます。